# How to get string following some specific letters?

Tags: python, regex

How can I get string from some specific characters? (more specifically, get "test" from "A8 test")
In this case, "A8" is following a pattern like `"[A-Z]+[0-9]+"`.
So it can also be "C6 test","X90 test" and etc.

I've tried in Python using `"(?<=[A-Z]+[0-9]).+"`, which throws an Exception:
`"sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern."`

It means I should use fixed-width pattern such as `"(?<=[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})"`.

But actually it's not fixed-width. What can I do?

Comment: Just use capture groups as in `[A-Z]+[0-9]+(.+)`. Here take the first group.

Answer (score 2):

If you means get the rest behind pattern `"[A-Z]+[0-9]+"`, you can try this:

```
import re 

s1 = 'A8 test'
s2 = 'C6 123'
s3 = 'X90 test32'

# parentheses is what you want
p = re.compile("[A-Z]+[0-9]+ (\w+)")

print(p.findall(s1))
print(p.findall(s2))
print(p.findall(s3))
```

output:

```
['test']
['123']
['test32']
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group to get what you need.

```
>>> regexp = r"[A-Z]+[0-9]+ (.+)"
>>> re.search(regexp, "C6 test")[1]
"test"
>>> re.search(regexp, "X90 test")[1]
"test"
>>> re.search(regexp, "CBF58456 test")[1]
"test"
```

Note that the current pattern you show would pick up on *any number* of uppercase letters followed by any number of digits, as long as there's at least one of each. Also note that my example above would require a blank between the first part and the test string to capture.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `re.sub` to jettison part of `str` you do not need by simply using empty `str` as second argument:

```
import re
text = "X90 test"
t = re.sub("[A-Z]+[0-9]+ ","",text)
print(t) #test
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
ex = r"[A-Z]+[0-9]+ (.+)"
print(re.search(ex , "X90 test")[1])
print(re.search(ex , "C6 test")[1])
print(re.search(ex , "CBF58456 test")[1])
```

Output

```
test
test
test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string, then get your string.

```py
>>> re.split(r'([A-Z]+[0-9]+ )(test)', 'A8 test')
['', 'A8 ', 'test', '']
```

Or you can write a simple function to find your string in the whole string by not using regex.